# Get average duration per week-day from a list of records with start and end date

Tags: sql, postgresql, cockroachdb

I have a input table with three columns :

- `id` => string
- `start_date` => timestamptz
- `end_date` => timestamptz

I want to get the average duration in seconds (end_date - start_date) per **week-day** number over records.

My problem is : If I have a record where interval between start_date and end_date is 4 days, I want to get the result per day, not only at the `start_date` or `end_date`, and if I have no records between 3 weeks for example, take no value for a weekday as 'zero' value in the average.

Example :

| id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 (Friday to Sunday) | 2021-03-12T01:00:00.000Z | 2021-03-14T01:00:00.000Z |
| 2 (Friday) | 2021-03-12T01:00:00.000Z | 2021-03-12T05:00:00.000Z |
| 3 (Wed.) | 2021-03-03T16:00:00.000Z | 2021-03-03T17:00:00.000Z |

Expected result (european weekday here for example, sunday is 7) :

| weekday | avg_duration_seconds |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 1800 |
| 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 48600 |
| 6 | 86400 |
| 7 | 3600 |

Thank's for your help !

Comment: What is `weekday`?  This is not in your data and not defined in the question.

Comment: The day number in the week, 1 for monday, 2 for tuesday, ... 7 for sunday

Comment: CockroachDB or Postgres. Although Cockroach claims to be "compatible" they are not really the same as Postgres

Comment: Agree with you, but not the subject here.

Comment: 2021-03-02 was a  Tuesday, not a Wednesday and 2021-03-11 was a Thursday, not a Friday

Comment: A yes thx, edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: the following works on Postgres as you tagged that as well. I have no idea if this works on CockroachDB as well.

You can "expand" the start/end timestamps to days by using `generate_series()`. To calculate the effective duration on each day, the full days need to be treated differently than the partial days at the start and end. Once those timestamps are calculated it's easy to get the duration per day. The do a left join on all weekdays and group by them:

```
select x.weekday, 
       avg(extract(epoch from real_end - real_start)) as duration
from generate_series(1,7) as x(weekday) 
left join (      
    select t.id, 
           extract(isodow from g.dt) as weekday,
           case  
             when start_date < g.dt then date_trunc('day', g.dt)
             else start_date
           end as real_start, 
           case 
             when end_date::date > g.dt then date_trunc('day', g.dt::date + 1)
             else end_date
           end as real_end
    from the_table t
      cross join generate_series(start_date, end_date, interval '1 day') as g(dt)
  ) t on x.weekday = t.weekday
group by x.weekday  
order by x.weekday;
```

I am not 100% my expressions for "real_start" and "real_end" cover all corner cases, but it should be enough to get you started.

This gives a slightly different result than your expected one, because you have the weekdays wrong for 2021-03-02 and 2021-03-11.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ada89fa5a48075c68856774b5da9f3f7)

Comment: Thank you very much, working on cockroach db using `from the_table t, generate_series(start_date, end_date, interval '1 day') as g(dt)` syntax instead of the cross join